# Узнать город пользователя по ip

Tags: php, javascript, ip

Как определить, в каком городе находится посетитель сайта с помощью `php` или `js` (`html5 geolocation` **не предлагать!**).

Нужно узнать город, зная только `ip` пользователя, а также чтобы можно было использовать в *КОММЕРЧЕСКИХ* целях и название города выводилось *РУССКИМИ* буквами (т.к. есть множество сервисов, но у них названия городов выводятся на английском).

Comment: https://www.maxmind.com/ru/geoip-demo

Comment: Вы никогда это достоверно не узнаете. Я, например, нахожусь в Нижнем Новгороде по IP. И это далеко не рядом (500 км) от моего реального местоположения. Всё что полезно узнавать, так это только страну пользователя.

Comment: Точно вы не узнаете, тем-более по ип. точное местоположение можно определить только по `bssId`

Answer (score 2):

```
        //Можно через curl
    $request = file_get_contents("http://api.sypexgeo.net/json/".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); 
$array = json_decode($request);
echo $array->city->name_ru;
```

В интернете масса скриптов и сервисов если этот не нравится сможете найти другой

Comment: Это бесплатно и для коммерческого использования? Просто для меня это важно

Comment: @Ipad.labs да, https://sypexgeo.net/ru/faq/

Comment: Поправка 1: бесплатно и без регистрации дается только 10 000 запросов в месяц, это немного учитывая то, что на сайт заходят роботы. После регистрации дается еще 30 000 бонусных запросов. Поправка 2: file_get_contents - это не curl

Answer (score 0):

еще один сервис https://location.ekolesnyk.com

```
$url = 'https://location.ekolesnyk.com/api/v1/country/?apiKey={apiKey}&ip=www.google.com';
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($response, true); 

  if((isset($json['error']))){
  return $json['error']; //message error
  }

  return $json;
```